# How to change Tumblr default lightbox

Tags: jquery, image, lightbox, tumblr, magnific-popup

I've got a Tumblr blog [code: pastebin.com/f3GaqZSA ] and I would like to remove the default lightbox, because when I click on an image it shows the lightbox AND it goes to the single post page, which is quite annoying.

As you can see from the code, I tried to implement the Magnific Popup plugin, but it keeps showing the Tumblr default lightbox.

How can I remove the default lightbox?
How can I make the Magnific Popup plugin work?

[Please be clear, I'm a beginner!]

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
Here's the script I used for Magnific Popup: [script](http://pastebin.com/YGNjDQjn)

And here's the CSS: [CSS](http://pastebin.com/AekBDjjH)

I can't find the Tumblr default lightbox part of the code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please isolate the code relating to the the lightbox and also add the code you have tried for magnific popup? Sadly I doubt anyone will look through to two linked files to isolate the issue for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I added the codes.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the code for your implementation of the lightbox script. Just to clarify, this isn't a lightbox: http://duderedcat.tumblr.com/image/101434331939 its just a page. If you can post *your* code, it should be simple to resolve.